# Print the first in a Python "subdict"

Tags: python-2.7

I am running a script (Python2.7) that collects data from my Husqvarna Automower
I would like to store a bit of information in a variable to printout, but i seems like the information i like to get is in a subdict (dont know if thats the correct term)

If i run this in the script`pp.pprint(mow.status())`

I get this

```
{   u'batteryPercent': 99,
u'cachedSettingsUUID': u'59a88728-804a-47b6-824c-d2b093bd980e',
u'connected': False,
u'lastErrorCode': 0,
u'lastErrorCodeTimestamp': 0,
u'lastLocations': [   {   u'gpsStatus': u'USING_GPS_MAP',
                          u'latitude': 57.57352,
                          u'longitude': 12.047441666666666},
                      {   u'gpsStatus': u'USING_GPS_MAP',
                          u'latitude': 57.573521666666664,
                          u'longitude': 12.047431666666666},
                      {   u'gpsStatus': u'USING_GPS_MAP',
                          u'latitude': 57.573535,
                          u'longitude': 12.047445},
                      {   u'gpsStatus': u'USING_GPS_MAP',
                          u'latitude': 57.57356333333333,
                          u'longitude': 12.047563333333333},
                      {   u'gpsStatus': u'USING_GPS_MAP',
                          u'latitude': 57.573573333333336,
                          u'longitude': 12.047613333333333},
                      {   u'gpsStatus': u'USING_GPS_MAP',
                          u'latitude': 57.57349,
                          u'longitude': 12.047508333333333},
                      {   u'gpsStatus': u'USING_GPS_MAP',
                          u'latitude': 57.573485,
                          u'longitude': 12.047495},
                      {   u'gpsStatus': u'USING_GPS_MAP',
                          u'latitude': 57.57347166666667,
                          u'longitude': 12.047833333333333},
                      {   u'gpsStatus': u'USING_GPS_MAP',
                          u'latitude': 57.57348833333333,
                          u'longitude': 12.047818333333334},
                      {   u'gpsStatus': u'USING_GPS_MAP',
                          u'latitude': 57.573526666666666,
                          u'longitude': 12.047773333333334},
                      {   u'gpsStatus': u'USING_GPS_MAP',
                          u'latitude': 57.573526666666666,
                          u'longitude': 12.047771666666666},
                      {   u'gpsStatus': u'USING_GPS_MAP',
                          u'latitude': 57.57357666666667,
                          u'longitude': 12.047841666666667},
                      {   u'gpsStatus': u'USING_GPS_MAP',
                          u'latitude': 57.57354333333333,
                          u'longitude': 12.047875},
                      {   u'gpsStatus': u'USING_GPS_MAP',
                          u'latitude': 57.57358333333333,
                          u'longitude': 12.047835},
                      {   u'gpsStatus': u'USING_GPS_MAP',
                          u'latitude': 57.57357666666667,
                          u'longitude': 12.047818333333334},
                      {   u'gpsStatus': u'USING_GPS_MAP',
                          u'latitude': 57.573635,
                          u'longitude': 12.047693333333333},
                      {   u'gpsStatus': u'USING_GPS_MAP',
                          u'latitude': 57.57364666666667,
                          u'longitude': 12.04762},
                      {   u'gpsStatus': u'USING_GPS_MAP',
                          u'latitude': 57.57359,
                          u'longitude': 12.04724},
                      {   u'gpsStatus': u'USING_GPS_MAP',
                          u'latitude': 57.57359,
                          u'longitude': 12.047235},
                      {   u'gpsStatus': u'USING_GPS_MAP',
                          u'latitude': 57.57350666666667,
                          u'longitude': 12.047486666666666},
                      {   u'gpsStatus': u'USING_GPS_MAP',
                          u'latitude': 57.5735,
                          u'longitude': 12.047553333333333},
                      {   u'gpsStatus': u'USING_GPS_MAP',
                          u'latitude': 57.57351666666667,
                          u'longitude': 12.047533333333334},
                      {   u'gpsStatus': u'USING_GPS_MAP',
                          u'latitude': 57.57351666666667,
                          u'longitude': 12.04756},
                      {   u'gpsStatus': u'USING_GPS_MAP',
                          u'latitude': 57.57353333333333,
                          u'longitude': 12.047541666666667},
                      {   u'gpsStatus': u'USING_GPS_MAP',
                          u'latitude': 57.57353,
                          u'longitude': 12.047571666666666},
                      {   u'gpsStatus': u'USING_GPS_MAP',
                          u'latitude': 57.57346,
                          u'longitude': 12.047595},
                      {   u'gpsStatus': u'USING_GPS_MAP',
                          u'latitude': 57.57346,
                          u'longitude': 12.04761},
                      {   u'gpsStatus': u'USING_GPS_MAP',
                          u'latitude': 57.573431666666664,
                          u'longitude': 12.04773},
                      {   u'gpsStatus': u'USING_GPS_MAP',
                          u'latitude': 57.573435,
                          u'longitude': 12.047711666666666},
                      {   u'gpsStatus': u'USING_GPS_MAP',
                          u'latitude': 57.57346833333333,
                          u'longitude': 12.047578333333334},
                      {   u'gpsStatus': u'USING_GPS_MAP',
                          u'latitude': 57.573495,
                          u'longitude': 12.047641666666667},
                      {   u'gpsStatus': u'USING_GPS_MAP',
                          u'latitude': 57.57349333333333,
                          u'longitude': 12.04764},
                      {   u'gpsStatus': u'USING_GPS_MAP',
                          u'latitude': 57.57347333333333,
                          u'longitude': 12.047643333333333},
                      {   u'gpsStatus': u'USING_GPS_MAP',
                          u'latitude': 57.57346833333333,
                          u'longitude': 12.04771},
                      {   u'gpsStatus': u'USING_GPS_MAP',
                          u'latitude': 57.573478333333334,
                          u'longitude': 12.047773333333334},
                      {   u'gpsStatus': u'USING_GPS_MAP',
                          u'latitude': 57.57325,
                          u'longitude': 12.047635},
                      {   u'gpsStatus': u'USING_GPS_MAP',
                          u'latitude': 57.57324833333333,
                          u'longitude': 12.047635},
                      {   u'gpsStatus': u'USING_GPS_MAP',
                          u'latitude': 57.57324166666667,
                          u'longitude': 12.047633333333334},
                      {   u'gpsStatus': u'USING_GPS_MAP',
                          u'latitude': 57.57324166666667,
                          u'longitude': 12.047631666666666},
                      {   u'gpsStatus': u'USING_GPS_MAP',
                          u'latitude': 57.573285,
                          u'longitude': 12.047618333333334},
                      {   u'gpsStatus': u'USING_GPS_MAP',
                          u'latitude': 57.573301666666666,
                          u'longitude': 12.047596666666667},
                      {   u'gpsStatus': u'USING_GPS_MAP',
                          u'latitude': 57.573303333333335,
                          u'longitude': 12.047595},
                      {   u'gpsStatus': u'USING_GPS_MAP',
                          u'latitude': 57.57331166666667,
                          u'longitude': 12.047561666666667},
                      {   u'gpsStatus': u'USING_GPS_MAP',
                          u'latitude': 57.573315,
                          u'longitude': 12.047555},
                      {   u'gpsStatus': u'USING_GPS_MAP',
                          u'latitude': 57.57331666666666,
                          u'longitude': 12.047555},
                      {   u'gpsStatus': u'USING_GPS_MAP',
                          u'latitude': 57.57333833333333,
                          u'longitude': 12.047551666666667},
                      {   u'gpsStatus': u'USING_GPS_MAP',
                          u'latitude': 57.57342166666667,
                          u'longitude': 12.047566666666667},
                      {   u'gpsStatus': u'USING_GPS_MAP',
                          u'latitude': 57.573365,
                          u'longitude': 12.047553333333333},
                      {   u'gpsStatus': u'USING_GPS_MAP',
                          u'latitude': 57.573366666666665,
                          u'longitude': 12.047553333333333},
                      {   u'gpsStatus': u'USING_GPS_MAP',
                          u'latitude': 57.573346666666666,
                          u'longitude': 12.047558333333333}],
u'mowerStatus': u'OFF_DISABLED',
u'nextStartSource': u'WEEK_TIMER',
u'nextStartTimestamp': 1491782400,
u'operatingMode': u'AUTO',
u'showAsDisconnected': False,
u'storedTimestamp': 1491435026887L,
u'valueFound': True}
```

I can get for example the batteryPercent using

```
        dic_info = mow.status()

        Battery = dic_info.get('batteryPercent')

        print Battery
```

But how do i get the longitude and latitude in a similary way, i only need the first one?

Thanx Martin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to access `lastLocations`, that contains a `list of dicts`. When you get there, just access the element in position `[0]` and then use `['latitude']` or `['longitude']` to get their specific values.

```
d = dict(mow.status())

>>> print(d['lastLocations'][0])
{'latitude': 57.57352, 'gpsStatus': 'USING_GPS_MAP', 'longitude': 12.047441666666666}

>>> print(d['lastLocations'][0]['latitude'])
57.57352

>>> print(d['lastLocations'][0]['longitude'])
12.047441666666666
```

---

You can change the index at `print(d['lastLocations'][0]` to `[1]` or `[2]` to access the second and third element of this `list`, for example.

- `{u'gpsStatus': u'USING_GPS_MAP', u'latitude': 57.573521666666664, u'longitude': 12.047431666666666}`
- `{u'gpsStatus': u'USING_GPS_MAP', u'latitude': 57.573535, u'longitude': 12.047445}`

---

**P.s.:** You can use `print(len(d['lastLocations']))` to get the number of elements inside the `lastLocations` list.

```
>>> print(len(d['lastLocations']))
50
```

So now you know that you can't use an `index` bigger than `49`, or in other words, `50 - 1`.